# NSPredicate - convert arguments?

Tags: swift, nspredicate

Any idea how to do this in Swift 3?

```
let number: NSArray = [123, 456, 678]
let check = "1"
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "number.stringValue CONTAINS %@", check)

number.filtered(using: predicate)
```

The problem is .stringValue. Any idea how this can be done without using a block predicate and not using the standard filter function, but with a predicate as above?

Comment: Why are you using `NSArray` in `Swift`? You should use `Array<Int>` instead.

Comment: I know - just making up this example as the original problem is with a Result I'm getting back from Realm where I need to use a standard NSPredicate format. I can use a Swift Array for the above and use filter with no problem. Still trying to figure out how to convert an argument in the above.

Comment: *I can use a Swift Array for the above and use filter with no problem*. Why do you want to create a problem?

Comment: Then ask about the problem you are actually having and not some made up issue that is irrelevant. Either edit this question to contain the actual topic or delete it completely and create a new one. Result is of homogenous type, so this example has nothing to do with filtering Realm Result.

Comment: a) I made the above for people who never used Realm before. If the above can be solved, the Realm situation is solved as well.
b) why don't you go ahead and either try to answer my question about .stringValue (as an example) or just leave this question alone. There is no need to throw smart comments.

Comment: You won't get an answer for this comment that will be relevant to Realm, since this example you made up has nothing to do with Realm. Realm's Result collection is quite far from `NSArray` in its implementation, so the solution to the real problem lies really far from the solution to this really bad example. Instead of playing smart with people who are trying to help, why don't you make your own life easier and ask the question you actually need an answer for?

Comment: I JUST want to know - can you make the above example work with ONLY changing the predicate. This will help me, if not - no need to reply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The name of the array variable (here: "number") is not part of the key path of the array elements, so it is just:

```
let number: NSArray = [123, 456, 678]
let check = "6"
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "stringValue CONTAINS %@", check)

print(number.filtered(using: predicate)) // [456, 678]
```

Or with "SELF", if you want to be more explicit:

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF.stringValue CONTAINS %@", check)
```

The "SELF" keyword is explained in [Predicate Format String Syntax](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html) in the "Predicate Programming Guide":

> SELF
>   Represents the object being evaluated.